# ¿Cómo controlar el alto de una celda en una tabla?

Tags: php, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo controlar la altura de la celda que se aprecia en la imagen, probé colocando un alto definido en la celda, pero no funciona.  El texto viene de una base de datos mysql y también hice trim con php.  El código del html es:

```
<table id="decomisoTabla" border=1 name="decomisoTabla" class="decomisoTabla">
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color: #bebebe;vertical-align: middle;height:50px" rowspan="1" align="center"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>7</b></span></font></th>
        <th style="background-color: #bebebe;vertical-align: middle;"><font class="detalles2"><b>N.U.E.</b></font></th>
        <td style="width:50px;vertical-align: middle;">4444444</td>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;width: 200px;"><span style="word-wrap: break-word;">Comprimidos redondos color amarillo trirranurados, colorComprimidos redondos color amarillo trirranurados, colorComprimidos redondos color amarillo trirranurados, colorComprimidos redondos color amarillo trirranurados, colorComprimidos redondos                        gfhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfÃ³</span></td>
    </tr>           
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #bebebe;width:125px;vertical-align: middle;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Tipo de Entrega</b></span></font></th>
        <td colspan="2" style="width:200px">Comprimidos color celeste, ranurados en cruz</td>       
        <th style="background-color: #bebebe;vertical-align: middle;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Presunta Sustancia</b></span></font></th>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">FÃ¡rmacos (gramos)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Peso Bruto</b></span></font></th>
        <td style="width:22%;"><span>7</span></td><td style="width:18%;">Gramo(s)</td>
        <th style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Peso Neto</b></span></font></th>
        <td style="width:22%;">2</td><td style="width:20%;">Gramo(s)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberias incluir tu codigo.  Sin el, es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: agregado, es código de pruebas, falta agregar más clases.

Comment: En ese codigo si funciona la altura,

Comment: eso veo, el código pasa por html2pdf, quizás ahí está el problema

Answer (score 0):

tiene en el th de la tabla el siguiente error:

```
<th style="background-color: #bebebe;vertical-align: middle;height:50px" rowspan="1" align="center"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>7</b></span></font></th>
```

esta mal escrita la propiedad por eso no te da problemas (va el numero sin px), borra toda la propiedad height para evitar futuras fallas

Comment: ma causa duda por que dices que usar px no es válido]?

Comment: en este caso especifico no lee px como una medida valida

Comment: si mi pregunta es por que?

Comment: Porque el sistema sobre entiende que estas hablando de pixeles por eso no lee la expresion "px".